# Webklex\PHPIMAP Modern Auth Not Working office 365

Tags: laravel, oauth, office365, imap

Webklex\PHPIMAP Modern Auth Not Working 365
Can anyone please help me on this?.
please see the images for code
i am able to get the access token but getting authentication error

code for connecting to the mailbox [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTz70.png)

code to get the access token[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNKYF.png)

Comment: Your question is the 14th so far, so look at [the previous 13](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimap%5D+office365+oauth). And BTW, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KluM5.png is hardly enough information to answer. Put the text in text form so it can be read, and so google will find it. SO is meant to be searched.

Comment: Please do not provide images of code.  please put your code _in the question_

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are having difficulty connecting to Outlook using webklex/PHPIMAP with Modern Authentication for your Office 365 account. Microsoft has recently announced the Exchange Online capability to use OAuth authentication for POP and IMAP and SMTP protocols. In order to use OAuth, you will need to obtain an access token first. Once you have the token, please proceed by setting the authentication to OAuth and configure your app with the appropriate application permissions. You can refer to the Microsoft documentation for more detailed instructions on how to set up Modern Authentication using OAuth.

bye

Comment: thank you for responding.can u please guide me on how to get access token.

Comment: To obtain an access token, you will need to register your application with the corresponding OAuth authorization server. Depending on the authorization server, this may require you to create an app, register a client ID and secret, and configure the necessary scopes and redirect URLs. Once everything is set up, you will be able to generate an access token that can be used to authenticate your application with the corresponding OAuth authorization server. For more detailed instructions, please refer to the Microsoft documentation.